# Vuex nuxt mapstate : DOM not reacting to vuex state change

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I'd like to make 2 vuetify v-switch.
The first one toggle a boolean on true/false.
The second, is disabled if the first one is  false, and isnt if its true.
If the first switch is passed as false when the second is true, the second should be set to false and therefore, disabled.

Here is what I've done so far :

```
 computed: {
    ...mapState({
      propertyType: state => state.propertyTypes.current
    })
  }
```

Here are the code for the 2 switches

```
  <v-switch
    id="is-filter"
    v-model="propertyType.is_filter"
    flat
    class="mt-0"
    @change="propertyType.default_filter = false
  >
    // template stuff
  </v-switch>
  <v-switch
    id="default-filter"
    v-model="propertyType.default_filter"
    :disabled="!propertyType.default_filter"
    flat
    class="mt-0"
  >
    // template stuff
  </v-switch>
```

As you can see, the v-model is set on the "imported" state object. Note that state.propertyTypes.current is an object, and has multiples keys and values.

The issue i'm having here is whenever i toggle off the first switch when the second is true, the second is set disabled, but it's value doesn't change in DOM. The vuex state object is updated, but not the DOM.

See image, representing the "vuex bindings" imported but mapState
[image]

DOM :

[image]

How can I fix this and have DOM to be reactiv to this vuex bindings objects ?

Thanks by advance for any help !

Comment: Vue tracks reactively only the first level of Object keys/properties - and you have second level. You will need to use a Vuex getter or a watcher. And by the way, it is a bad practice to directly mutate Vuex state - you should use Vuex mutators.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it's more clear to me now. I'll have to have a mapGetters, like I did for the mapState, with the dot notation, is that right ?

Comment: I can't say without seeing your code. `mapGetters` takes an array of getter names - so the getter functions should return each of the 2nd-level properties you're interested in, either 1 property per getter or as a new Object from a single getter.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call mapState from computed like that:
Here is a copy of my code which shows the namespace and state name:

```
computed: {
        ...mapState("your_vuex_namespace_name", ["propertyType"]),
    }
```

I hope it helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, i'll try it as soon as I can, but to be clear, the "spacename" is the name of the objet / array in my state and the  other is the file name in my vuex store folder ?

Comment: You are welcome. By namespace I mean the module path when you register your module inside vuex root store file.

Comment: By "['propertypType']", I mean the state object or array declared inside the state of your vuex.